# Cannot enable javascript for GWT application using Selenium WebClient or HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, gwt, selenium-webdriver, webclient, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to get the HTML page source in order to test the GUI for a **GWT application** using **headless browser testing**. First I tried to get the content of the page using **HtmlUnitDriver**, like the following:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit();

//set an userId header
capabilities.setCapability("id", "userId");

HtmlUnitDriver unitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);

//enabled javascript
unitDriver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

unitDriver.get("http://localhost:portNo/example/");

String pageSource = unitDriver.getPageSource();
```

The second way of doing it was by using **WebClient**:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

//enabled javascript
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//set an userId header
webClient.addRequestHeader("id", "userId");

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:portNo/example/");
String contentAsString = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Yet, in the both cases I get the same result. The result **does not contain the actual content of the page**, and it displays the following:

```
</iframe>
    <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->    <noscript>

      &lt;div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif"&gt;
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      &lt;/div&gt;

    </noscript>
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="frameId" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:none" tabindex="-1">
    </iframe>
```

Is there anything I can do/enable in order to get the actual content of the page? Thank you!

Comment: Both, unitDriver.getPafeSource() and page.getWebReponse() are returning host page content (see http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideHostPage). This is the actual content. But I suspect you want to check some elements after bootstraping. In this case you should use DOM related API from HtmlUnit/WebClient (e.g. page.asText, page.getByXpath)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Alexander. You are right, I am looking for DOM elements in the page, but the problem is that I am not getting anything from it when calling unitDriver.findElementByClassName("listGrid"), for example. Also, the  page.asText() method only provides me the page title, so that's not very useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by setting a timeout in order for the javascript files to load.

So, after doing this:

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:portNo/example/");
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000); //time in milliseconds
```

the page had the content and I can find the expected DOM elements.